# Unable to signinWithCredential() for Ffacebook OAuth with Firebase

Tags: facebook, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I've been unable to successfully use Firebase's signinWithCredentials() for a Facebook login. I've checked and rechecked that i'm using the correct app_id and app_secret on Firebase's authentication page as well as confirmed my settings and added a redirect uri to Facebooks developer console.

I'm using a react-native application built on top of expo. My auth flow is to use expo to display the facebook UI and sign the user in.

```
const { type, token } = await 
Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync('a_secret_number', {
permissions: ['public_profile', 'email']
});
```

This successfully returns a token which I then try to integrate with firebase by creating a credential:

```
const credential = await 
firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(token);
```

the credential looks something like:

```
{
"accessToken": "EAAIgv4Sw9TQBAA1G30ZC71qyjcRLM4o9kWVxf1oGhZAWAdGVeZBHrSdNADHGxCeZCzyWxZAjEPM1iZCXXdsadsadsaga321432432dsaddsadsadas34214234324asdasdsadsapv1W3ybqtziQC4JRKZA5hD4a50JrVC1rfoFiFZAJZCcoGoRViTQtgevbnNEx8s7ZA1a1Xd6xOQBsnZC1qdJzOTgZDZD",
"providerId": "facebook.com",
}
```

So, up until now i've confirmed the data is formatted correctly and contains something to send to firebase.

Finally,

```
try {
await firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
}
```

And the error message:

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"invalid","message":"Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"EpP6p3IVs3a\"}}"}],"code":400,"message":"Unsuccessful debug_token response from Facebook: {\"error\":{\"message\":\"(#100) The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App\",\"type\":\"OAuthException\",\"code\":100,\"fbtrace_id\":\"EpP6p3IVs3a\"}}"}}
```

After Several hours of headbanging and trying to find solutions for this error, i've come to stack overflow for help. Any help or guidance would be appreciated :)

Module Versions:

```
"expo": "23.0.0",
        "firebase": "^4.10.0",
```

Comment: it seems like you aren't using the right app id -> "The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App"

Comment: That was exactly the case. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolved it by going to firebase console > Authentication > Sign in method (https://console.firebase.google.com/project/your-project-name/authentication/providers), and editing the facebook provider, inserting the correct App id and App secret from the corresponding fb-app found in the facebook developer dashboard (https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your-app-number/).